# Want to find the best path with the largest score in the field

Tags: c++

I don't know how to make my program find the best path.

So, the program i'm making has to find the path for the largest possible score, the only direction that it can move can only be down and right and it starts at coordinates 0 0, and every field has a value of 0 before the input and i have made list and the way the field should look like for me to see where the values are.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int f=0; // f is the number of fields with value assigned
    int field [5] [5]; //The game field
    int x=0, y=0; //coordinates for the field
    int n=0; //The Score assigned for each field
    int maxScore=0; //The largest score gathered from the field
    int TempScore=0; //Temporary max score. used for checking if it's higher then the max score, then if it is tempScore = maxScore
    int fSpaces=5;
    int k=1;

    for(int i = 0;i<fSpaces;i++){for(int j = 0;j<fSpaces;j++){field[i][j]=0;}} //TESTED Works fine, assigns every field 0 value

    cout<<"How many fields?: ";
    cin>>f;
    cout<<"Coordinates"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<f;i++){
        cin>>x>>y>>n;
        field[x][y]=n;
    }

    //cout<<"All Fields"<<endl;


    //THIS LISTS ALL OF THE FIELD VALUES

    /*
    for(int i = 0;i<fSpaces;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<fSpaces;j++){
                    cout<<k<<". "<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<field[i][j]<<endl;
                    k++;
            }
    }
    */

    //THIS DISPLAYS THE FIELD

    for(int i = 0;i<fSpaces;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<fSpaces;j++){
                    cout<<field[j][i]<<" _|_ ";

            }cout<<endl;
    }

    //This counts every value together witout being restricted

    for(int i = 0;i<fSpaces;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<fSpaces;j++){
                 if(field[i][j]>0){maxScore+=field[i][j];}
            }
    }

    cout<<"All of the values together add up to "<<maxScore<<endl;
    maxScore=0;

    //This count values with restrictions
//Here i tried something, but i couldn't figure it out
/*
    for(int i = 0;i<fSpaces;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<fSpaces;j++){
                 if(field[i][j]>0){
                        maxScore+=field[i][j]; //

                 }
            }
    }

    cout<<"Counted value max score is "<<maxScore<<endl;
*/
    return 0;
}
//Example for an input
//3
//0 1 5
//2 2 10
//2 0 1
```

The only thing i have done is wrote the input, how it should be, first typing how many fields have values and then typing in coordinates and how much score does that field have.

Comment: The question is extremely unclear. What do you consider *the best path*? What is your exact question? Have you heard of graph traversals? You might be interested in reading more about it.

Comment: @Fureeish I will try to explain it, i input the values for fields and from the coordinates x=0, y=0, the program can only go right and down, and from the input that you have typed in, fields of value, the program sums up the score from each field and the path with the biggest sum is the best path, it's ok if you don't understand, it's hard for me to explain.

Comment: Reverse an algorithm for finding the shortest path from a graph. Something like Dijkstra or A* should be sufficient and simple enough. Originally, those two algorithms are used to find the *shortest* path, but it's trivial to alter them in such a way that the *longest* path will be considered the best. Again, as of right now, we lack information what have you tried so far.